# XML Commenting -- How to properly mark a see also tag?

Tags: generics, methods, extension-methods, nullable, xml-comments

I have the following and I'm not sure how to properly reference this in my XML commenting:

```
public static class FooExtensions
{
    public static Nullable<T> FooX<T>(this Nullable<T> foo) { ... }
}


public class Bar
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Bar Function
    /// </summary>
    /// <seealso cref="??"/>
    public void BarFunc() { ... }
}
```

So, my guess is `<seealso cref="M:MyNamespace.FooExtensions.FooX{T}(this Nullable{T} foo)"/>`, but I'm not 100% if that's correct. Does anyone know?

---

Oh, and I have the ECMA PDF document, but I still can't really figure it out even with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to mark the `this` portion of the parameter, nor the name of it, so you should be able to use this:

```
<seealso cref="MyNamespace.FooExtensions.FooX{T}(Nullable{T})"/>
```